Laravel - Retrieve latest record from a grouped collection
I have a model called answer. which has columns student_id, status, and question_id. if the student entered a answer, teacher can ask to correct their answer and submit answer again. so i would change the status of old answer to 'reSubmit'. Now i want to list for students, the questions that had been asked to resubmit.



Id
Student id
Question id
status




1
1
1
resubmit


2
2
2
resubmit


3
3
1
resubmit


4
4
1
New



I want to return only question id 2 here which has status resubmit. other question with status resubmit has latest record New.
How can i achieve this ?
I have tried with group_by but that doesnt seems to be working.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please [edit] your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] a Good Question page for details on how to best help us help you.

Post what you have tried so far and your model relationships if you have such

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

To return only question id 2, which has status resubmit and no new status you can make use of relations:
// get all questions that have answers with
// at least one status "resubmit" and no "new" status
// this will give you a list of questions waiting to be resubmitted
$questions = Question::query()
  ->whereHas('answers', function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('status', 'resubmit')
      ->where('status', '!=', 'new');
  })
  ->get();

